# Embedding a header include into each webpage of my website

Tags: html, include

Is it possible to have header and footer includes within your normal web pages so that you dont have to repeat so much code on each page?

I know that you can do this with php but what if your building a website purely based in html?

If there is no answer or no way around this, does this mean that I have to repeat my navigation bar code on each page for example?

Thank you for any help

Dale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple solutions without using server side includes, but they are pretty bad:

- Frames/Iframes
- Load the content with javascript (AJAX request, or store the HTML in the js file)

If you can't use any of these, then yes - you'd have to repeat your code in each file. If server side includes are an option for you, you should just use them.

Comment: I see you've accepted the answer, what did you decide to do? Depending on your use case, the js solution might be ok.